# Extract max value from each group in google sheet

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula

I have a data sheet that looks something like this:

```
Type Value
A    20
A    23
B    22
C    8
C    11
C    14
D    4
E    9
E    13
```

How would I achieve 2 columns filled with max falue from each group, like this:

```
Type Value
A    23
B    22
C    14
D    4
E    13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=SORTN(SORT(A1:B, 1, 1, 2, 0), 9^9, 2, 1, 1)
```

[image: 0]